# New to Boostrap; how can I clean this code up + achieve the desired affect?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**EDIT:** See updated JS Fiddle link at the bottom of this question; I achieved the desired affect but still feel as though the code can be "cleaner"!

I've been experimenting with HTML/CSS for a while now but I'm building my first layout now using Twitter-Bootstrap. This is the first question I've had to ask, I really appreciate all input.

I feel like the section of code that I'm sharing can be "cleaned up." I've got it looking *mostly* like what I want but I can't help but think there's an easier way to achieve what I want.

See this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j30hb4dz/).

What I'm trying to do is this: on md+ size screens have two rows of diamonds, 4 on the first row and 3 on the second. When the user is on a small or x-small screen, the diamonds shift to three rows, 3 on the first row, 2 on the second, and 3 on the third. I want them very slightly spaced apart. Seeing the JS Fiddle, I've got it looking how I want on md+ screens, but the problem is that I can't seem to get row 1 and 3 on small and x-small screens to align properly with the second row.

What is the best way to do this? My way seems too messy. I'd just like to use HTML/CSS in case someone has JS disabled. THANK YOU. :)

```
<section class="container-fluid diamonds">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="xsrow1">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 xsright no-padding"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 no-padding"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="xsrow2">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-4 no-padding"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-4 no-padding"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 mdrow2">
      <div class="xsrow2">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="xsrow3">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 xsright no-padding"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 no-padding"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>


.no-padding {
  padding: 0!important;
  padding-right: 3px!important;
  padding-left: 3px!important;
  margin: 0!important;
}

.diamonds {
  position: relative;
}

.diamonds img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .xsrow1 img, .xsrow3 img {
    width: 66.66667%!important;
    height: auto;
  }
  .xsright {
    text-align: right;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .mdrow2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    left:0%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Well, I figured out a method that works for me, although I still feel it is messy. The updated [JS Fiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/j30hb4dz/2/) If anyone has an easier method please feel free to share. :)

Answer (score -2):

You could use a preprocessor, add more semantic classes to the markup and remove the layout classes (col etc), mixin the styles you want those classes.

Comment: hey all, if you're going to downvote, some feedback about why would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I have never actually messed with what you were talking about. I did figure it out but I can't help but think there was an easier way.

Comment: Adding more confusion isn't a solution. It's a recipe for disaster. OP was looking for help simplifying code.

Comment: unfortunately, because bootstrap is a library, you have to dirty the markup because you have no way to reuse classes in css. Preprocessors allow you to do that, so if you moved the bootstrap stuff to a single class in css, it would significantly clean up the markup